# 0x2726 error while signing pdf file with IText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I am trying to sign pdf file programmatically with IText in java with my own provider. When I sign with p12 file all is fine. But when I try to sign with token, i dont have any exception. But when I try to open signed pdf I get this error 0x2726.

Here my signed file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz1LIekMx5F8WHFDRHpTTUU2SVU/view?usp=sharing
pls, Help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException {

    char[] pass = PASSWORD.toCharArray();
    MyProvider provider = new MyProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStoreUtil.getKeyStore(Storage.MYTOKEN, "TOEKN_PATH", pass, provider);

    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchProviderException | FileNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | PrivilegedActionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PDFSIGN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    PDFSIGN app = new PDFSIGN();
    PrivateKey pk = null;
    Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[1];
    Enumeration<String> als = ks.aliases();
    String alias = (String) als.nextElement();
    System.err.println(alias);
    Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);
    ASN1InputStream ais = new ASN1InputStream(cert.getEncoded());
    X509CertificateStructure x509Struct = new X509CertificateStructure((ASN1Sequence) ais.readObject());
    ais.close();
    X509CertificateObject certificateObject = new X509CertificateObject(x509Struct);
    chain[0] = certificateObject;
    passw = "123456";
    pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, passw.toCharArray());
    app.sign(SRC, DEST, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Ghent", crlList, null, null, 0);
}

public void sign(String src, String dest, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider, CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location, Collection<CrlClient> crlList,
        OcspClient ocspClient, TSAClient tsaClient, int estimatedSize)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
    ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    ExternalDigest digest = new ProviderDigest(provider);
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);

}
```

Comment: First of all you have included a 500 KB CRL. That alone may exceed some crypto libraries' capabilities. That been said, there seems to be an issue with the signature value itself. but could you provide a signature without that giant CRL for analysis?

Comment: Hello! CRL here does not matter. I can remove crl but result is the same.

Comment: Yes, most likely it does not matter, it just helps to get a handy object to analyze. (And you surely won't want to embed that CRL in real life documents either...)